# How to add a method to a class / how to make the runtime think a class contains a method?

Tags: java, android, xposed, xposed-framework

I have an app that I try to make work on my phone, but on my phone I don't have some of the vendor-libs needed to run the app.

I created a Magisk+Xposed module that patches in the missing classes, but it turns out that the vendor added stuff to core android classes (like `com.android.View`).

I successfully patched the `ClassLoader`s, made reflection work, but some calls to vendor-added methods are direct, so the app crashes.

How do I add that methods to the classes, or how can I tell the runtime to look for these methods elsewhere?

Comment: inherit those classes, or create a new class with the same name. I've worked on a project once, where the first developers thought it would be a good idea to create their own String and Object classes. Imagine how much fun that was.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, good idea, but those classes get preloaded by android, so there is no chance to "sneak" my own copies of those classes in.

Comment: and you think String and Object aren't pre loaded in Java? Most likely, if the code you want in those classes isn't there, there's a reason for that.

Comment: Yes, the reason is that Samsung thought it was a good idea to modify android core classes. 
Those classes are loaded as soon as the process is started

Comment: Instead of patching the system I would patch the app. That should be far easier than modifying the whole system.

Comment: xposed is nowadays provided by lsposed so it's only app-scoped anyway.
But what did you have in mind for patching the app?

Comment: @Stultuske actually I got class replacing working partially even though they are preloaded, but I got very strange VerifyErrors where it expects another version of some class later on.